# Is this PSU switch in the right position?

Tags: cpu, bios, power

My CPU is not booting (no BIOS screen appears on HDMI connected display). I am not sure if the switch is in right position in picture below.

[image]

Comment: You should have a cable plugged in for the computer to work, the switch is a simple on/off switch, if it's on the 'O' side, your computer will simply not turn on, as if the cable was not plugged in no damage will be done.

Comment: The system looks really rusty, I'd wonder if there's some hardware failure somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The switch is in the on position, this is correct for a working machine.

However the bios not showing up on the connected monitor maybe due to a huge number of other issues.

Comment: lol. But there is no power cord ...

Comment: I suspect this may be a problem, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Umm depending on where you live different areas have different voltages your psu says 230V on that yellow sticker generally in the us wall sockets are around 125V I believe so maybe if there’s a switch on your psu generally red flick it to the 125 or 115 v option and see if that does justice if there isn’t one you might wanna look into a new power supply unit